# Graph API not returning all photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

When I query photos I don't see as many photos as I do on Facebook. For example if I use FQL to find all photos with me in them, I get back about a 100 less photos than I see on Facebook if I look at photos of me.

Is this a privacy issue? I have noticed that the some users don't have any photos returned. Is there anyway to get all the images that I can see on Facebook through the graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a privacy issue. Facebook won't return photos via the API for users who have restricted the privacy on them below "Public." This could be a global setting for all posts or an individual setting on a single post. This goes for many other user objects as well.